# How do one should set a custom agent pool in DevOps release definition?

Tags: azure, rest, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I create release definitions using **DevOps REST APIs**. Due to lack of documentation I used to capture HTTP requests and examine JSON payload.

I'm able to set a release using **Azure agent pools**. It follows only the relevant node:

```json
"deploymentInput": {
    "parallelExecution": {
        "parallelExecutionType": 0
    },
    "agentSpecification": {
        "identifier": "windows-2019"
    },
    "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
    "artifactsDownloadInput": {},
    "queueId": 749,
    "demands": [],
    "enableAccessToken": false,
    "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
    "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1,
    "condition": "succeeded()",
    "overrideInputs": {},
    "dependencies": []
}
```

I want to set a **custom defined agent pool**, but if I try to capture the request I still can't undertand how to set it. This is the full JSON of an empty release with custom agent set:

```json
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "New release pipeline",
    "source": 2,
    "comment": "",
    "createdOn": "2020-10-31T10:02:19.034Z",
    "createdBy": null,
    "modifiedBy": null,
    "modifiedOn": "2020-10-31T10:02:19.034Z",
    "environments": [
        {
            "id": -1,
            "name": "Stage 1",
            "rank": 1,
            "variables": {},
            "variableGroups": [],
            "preDeployApprovals": {
                "approvals": [
                    {
                        "rank": 1,
                        "isAutomated": true,
                        "isNotificationOn": false,
                        "id": 0
                    }
                ],
                "approvalOptions": {
                    "executionOrder": 1
                }
            },
            "deployStep": {
                "tasks": [],
                "id": 0
            },
            "postDeployApprovals": {
                "approvals": [
                    {
                        "rank": 1,
                        "isAutomated": true,
                        "isNotificationOn": false,
                        "id": 0
                    }
                ],
                "approvalOptions": {
                    "executionOrder": 2
                }
            },
            "deployPhases": [
                {
                    "deploymentInput": {
                        "parallelExecution": {
                            "parallelExecutionType": 0
                        },
                        "agentSpecification": null,
                        "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
                        "artifactsDownloadInput": {},
                        "queueId": 1039,
                        "demands": [],
                        "enableAccessToken": false,
                        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                        "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1,
                        "condition": "succeeded()",
                        "overrideInputs": {},
                        "dependencies": []
                    },
                    "rank": 1,
                    "phaseType": 1,
                    "name": "Agent job",
                    "refName": null,
                    "workflowTasks": [],
                    "phaseInputs": {
                        "phaseinput_artifactdownloadinput": {
                            "artifactsDownloadInput": {},
                            "skipArtifactsDownload": false
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "runOptions": {},
            "environmentOptions": {
                "emailNotificationType": "OnlyOnFailure",
                "emailRecipients": "release.environment.owner;release.creator",
                "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
                "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                "enableAccessToken": false,
                "publishDeploymentStatus": true,
                "badgeEnabled": false,
                "autoLinkWorkItems": false,
                "pullRequestDeploymentEnabled": false
            },
            "demands": [],
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "conditionType": 1,
                    "name": "ReleaseStarted",
                    "value": ""
                }
            ],
            "executionPolicy": {
                "concurrencyCount": 1,
                "queueDepthCount": 0
            },
            "schedules": [],
            "properties": {
                "LinkBoardsWorkItems": false,
                "BoardsEnvironmentType": "unmapped"
            },
            "preDeploymentGates": {
                "id": 0,
                "gatesOptions": null,
                "gates": []
            },
            "postDeploymentGates": {
                "id": 0,
                "gatesOptions": null,
                "gates": []
            },
            "environmentTriggers": [],
            "owner": {
                "displayName": "Giacomo Stelluti Scala",
                "id": "3617734a-1751-66f2-8343-c71c1398b5e6",
                "isAadIdentity": true,
                "isContainer": false,
                "uniqueName": "giacomo.stelluti@dev4side.com",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/dev4side/"
            },
            "retentionPolicy": {
                "daysToKeep": 30,
                "releasesToKeep": 3,
                "retainBuild": true
            },
            "processParameters": {}
        }
    ],
    "artifacts": [],
    "variables": {},
    "variableGroups": [],
    "triggers": [],
    "lastRelease": null,
    "tags": [],
    "path": "\\test-poc",
    "properties": {
        "DefinitionCreationSource": "ReleaseNew",
        "IntegrateJiraWorkItems": "false",
        "IntegrateBoardsWorkItems": false
    },
    "releaseNameFormat": "Release-$(rev:r)",
    "description": ""
}
```

Where do this is agent is set? Anyone knows how to do it properly?

Any help really appreciated.

Giacomo S. S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58597833/how-to-set-a-agent-queue-in-a-release-definition-using-rest-api).

```json
"deploymentInput": {
    "parallelExecution": {
        "parallelExecutionType": 0
    },
    "agentSpecification": null,
    "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
    "artifactsDownloadInput": {},
    "queueId": 1039,
    "demands": [],
    "enableAccessToken": false,
    "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
    "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1,
    "condition": "succeeded()",
    "overrideInputs": {},
    "dependencies": []
}
```

**agentSpecification** must be `null` and **queueId** must be set.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Done! Thank you and have a nice day you too :)